# Android - Successful Install Notification Icon - Jellybean

Tags: android

When some applications finish installing or updating, the app's launcher icon is placed with the install notice like this:
[image]

How can I have my app's icon show up when it finishes installing as well?

Comment: Could you state your question clearer?
If you are asking how to push notification in Android, please check this link

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Comment: @Ethan I edited my question. I want my app icon to show up when it installs. Does that make sense?

Comment: This notification is created by GooglePlay app when you install any app from GooglePlay. When users install your app from GooglePlay, they would see the same thing. The icon shown will be your app icon when submitting to GooglePlay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that you don't. The notification you see there for Google Calendar is from the Play Store (note the shopping bag icon in the lower corner). If you created a notification, you'd risk annoying users by saying what's already been said. Also, you can't generate a notification when your app is finished installing because it hasn't run yet. The only way it can run the first time is by the user launching it, which means they already know it's installed.

*edit*
I understand that it may be confusing that you don't see the notification or automatic icon when you install your app via adb, but these things will automatically happen when users install it via the Google Play Store.

Comment: So I guess I just wasn't thinking, this makes sense. Always installing via adb, you don't get to experience the same _excitement_ of the play store lol

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything. This feature is a part of Google Play, and it handles it automatically.